# Bandwidth usage of HttpClient.GetStringAsync

Tags: c#, .net, web-scraping, dotnet-httpclient

I'm using [HttpClient.GetStringAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.getstringasync?view=net-6.0) to make a web scraping app, and the method will be called on over 5000 web pages during a single run. The pages themselves are pretty simple, and all I'm doing is parsing the source to extract some strings, but I'm curious about what sort of a hit this will have on my web bandwidth.

Does `GetStringAsync` only download the source, or will the embedded resources such as images, google maps controls, scripts, etc... have to actually load/run too at some point while the method's doing it's thing?

Here's an example of what the chrome network monitor tool shows when I load one of the pages I'm interested in:

[image]

All I care about is the circled figure at the top, since that's my source code. Is that all the `GetStringAsync` method will need to download, or will other more data-intensive stuff happen in the background too and bloat this figure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HttpClient is not a web browser (engine), and it does not behave like a web browser.

*HttpClient.GetStringAsync* will only receive (download) the response/resource from the server. *HttpClient* is not going to analyze and parse what that resource might be. From the perspective of *HttpClient.GetStringAsync* it's just trying to obtain a response from the server whose payload is supposed to be text data (a string). That's it. Whether the response is some HTML text, some json text, or just some letter soup is of no concern to *HttpClient*, because *HttpClient* is not a web browser engine.

In summary:

> Does GetStringAsync only download the source, or will the embedded resources such as images, google maps controls, scripts, etc...

It only downloads the source, because *HttpClient* is not a web browser engine.